# A special kind of Thue equation

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $F(x,y)$ be a binary form of degree $n \geq 3$, integer coefficients, and non-zero discriminant $\Delta(F)$. Recall that a Thue equation is an equation of the form

(1) 
$$\displaystyle F(x,y) = h,$$

where $x,y,h$ are integers, not all zero. It is well-known that for $h \ne 0$ this equation has finitely many solutions in integers $x$ and $y$, as can be shown by methods of Diophantine approximation (and this was done by Axel Thue, hence the name of the equation).

I am asking about a special kind of Thue equation, where $h$ is an integer dividing $\Delta(F)$. A (very) special case was dealt with by Bennett and Dahmen in the following paper: http://annals.math.princeton.edu/2013/177-1/p04

Is there further literature on this type of Thue equation? It seems that it is a natural question to ask. The reason why the case $n = 2$ was excluded is because in this case the answer is quite simple, and is basically completely answered using genus theory. In particular, when $F$ is a primitive integral binary quadratic form and $\Delta(F)$ is a fundamental discriminant, then the equation (1) is soluble if and only if the $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$-equivalence class of $F$ parametrizes the ideal class corresponding to $h$ (this is in fact well-defined, since any prime factor $p$ of $h$ has order at most 2 in the ideal class group and hence factorizing $(p)$ into $\mathfrak{p}_1 \mathfrak{p_2}$, the two factors are in the same class; hence any factorization of $(h)$ yields the same class). Such a succinct answer of course is impossible for higher degrees, hence requiring a totally different idea.